# PHP How to create folder and files on network share drive with IIS10

Tags: php, iis, iis-10, network-drive

I make PHP on IIS10 (windows server 2016) with FastCgi

I want to create upload edit folder and files on network share drive or map drive on server but not working got error

The server can access network share drive normally

> "PHP Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory"

```
$path = '\\\\172.55.55.55\\sharedir\\test';
$map = 'R:\\sharedir\\test'
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
```

Comment: IIS does not support mapped drives (`$map` in your case) in any way. UNC path can be used (`$path`) if you grant the application pool identity the correct permissions.

Comment: IIS will run the script with IIS_IUSR, so I guess this is a permission issue.

Comment: Please check that your server has access to that directory, It might be that the user running the server process simply doesn't have permission to read from or write to that file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

**(My idea)**

In this case the file is on another server, right?

1. Have to create .NET app to usage as API for create, delete file. (Web Socket)
2. Use IIS in another server and set folder path as FTP.

I hope it help you.
Sorry, if it can't solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).